# mysqldump output is not a valid Oracle "create table" format

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

I'm trying to move data from a MySQL database (5.6.32-78) to an Oracle Database (11g).  Using mysqldump, the output causes a "missing right parenthesis" error when creating a table in oracle.  ie...
mysqldump output:

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  "ID" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "column1" int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "column2" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Oracle is expecting the following (the order of NOT NULL and DEFAULT switched):

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  "ID" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "column1" int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  "column2" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Is there an option I'm missing to correct this?  I have a couple hundred tables to move and do not want to "reinvent the wheel" by writing procedure to get the correct output.
(--compatible=oracle does not make any difference).
Thanks.
Doug

---

I'll try to make the question more specific.

I am trying to migrate a MySQL to Oracle database and tried using mysqldump and various options, but it does not generate an Oracle usable output. I can't use Oracle's SQL Developer because it requires connecting to both the MySQL database (internet) and Oracle database (inside of a "no internet access" firewall) at the same time.  Is anyone aware of a way to create an Oracle friendly export of a MySQL database?

Comment: mysql and oracle are two different animals in many respects

Answer (score 1):

The order of `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT` is only one problem you'll face. There are many differences between MySQL and Oracle that cannot be fixed with mysqldump options.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible says:

> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for making dump output more compatible. For example, `--compatible=oracle` does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.

So you would have to do some hand-editing of your dump file before importing it to Oracle.

You're better off using Oracle SQL Developer to migrate your MySQL database to Oracle. You can find a step-by-step guide with videos here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/index.html

Note the steps for MySQL can be found by clicking the link "and others..." below the list of other commercial RDBMS products. Here's a direct link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I did read up and tried, pretty much, every available option for mysqldump to get the desired DDL out, but no success. I am aware of the disclaimer for using mysqldump.  I can't use the SQL Developer option because the Oracle Database is behind a "Never to connect to the internet" firewall, while the MySQL database in on Blue Host (can't connect to both at the same time).  I'm curious if anyone has successfully done a MySQL to Oracle migration using mysqldump.  My options are to either write a DDL package or setup a mySQL database inside the firewall and just import to that.